# How do I generate an Exception for this test?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I am trying to test the Exception handler in my application.
However I can't generate an Exception for the Constructor.

Normally, I would create a moq of an Object and then do a setup where a call to Object.method throws an Exception.  Then simply detect the Exception in the Test.

However, in this Constructor the only call is:

```
CredentialProfileStoreChain.TryGetAWSCredentials
```

CredentialProfileStoreChain.TryGetAWSCredentials can't be overridden so I can't use moq Setup to generate an Exception.

Code:

```
public class AWSDynamoDbManager : IAWSDynamoDbManager
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly AmazonDynamoDBClient _dynamoDbClient;
    //NOTE:  This setting is in the app.config of the calling application so that different uses can use different profiles
    private readonly string _awsProfileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSProfileName"];

    public AWSDynamoDbManager(CredentialProfileStoreChain chain, ILogger logger)
    {
       this._logger = logger;

       try
       {
           AWSCredentials awsCredentials;
           chain.TryGetAWSCredentials(_awsProfileName, out awsCredentials);
           _dynamoDbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(awsCredentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           logger.Error("Could Not Open DynamoDB");
           logger.Error("Error: " + e.Message);
           throw;
       }
   }
}
```

Test:

```
public void TestToSeeIfWeCatchTheExceptionIfWeCannotConnectToTheDatabase()
    {
        // arrange
        var mockLogger = new Mock<ILogger>();
        var mockChain = new Mock<CredentialProfileStoreChain>();

        // act / assert
        Assert.Catch<ArgumentException>(() => new AWSDynamoDbManager(mockChain.Object, mockLogger.Object));
    }
```

What can I use to force the Constructor to cause an Exception?

Comment: I suspect you probably can't. This is often the case for objects which sit at the interface of your code and external code: they need integration testing instead

Answer (score 0):

when my hands are tied because of an external dependency or static type, i use a wrapper, so that's what i'd use here. since we can't mock a CredentialProfileStoreChain, we throw it in a wrapper and use the wrapper.

```
public interface ICredentialProfileStoreChainWrapper
{
    void TryGetAWSCredentials(/*TODO*/);
}
public class CredentialProfileStoreChainWrapper
{
    readonly CredentialProfileStoreChain _Chain;
    public CredentialProfileStoreChainWrapper(CredentialProfileStoreChain chain)
    {
        _Chain = chain;
    }
    public void TryGetAWSCredentials(/*TODO*/)
    {
        _Chain.TryGetAWSCredentials(/*TODO*/);
    }
}
public class AWSDynamoDbManager : IAWSDynamoDbManager
{
    public AWSDynamoDbManager(ICredentialProfileStoreChainWrapper chainWrapper, ILogger logger)
    {
        //TODO
        chainWrapper.TryGetAWSCredentials(/*TODO*/);
    }
}
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void TestToSeeIfWeCatchTheExceptionIfWeCannotConnectToTheDatabase()
    {
        var wrapper = new Mock<ICredentialProfileStoreChainWrapper>();
        var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
        var manager = new AWSDynamoDbManager(wrapper.Object, logger.Object);
        wrapper.Setup(s => s.TryGetAWSCredentials(/*TODO*/)).Throws(new Exception());
        //TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: My thinking was that `AWSDynamoDbManager ` probably *is* the wrapper

Comment: @canton7 i was going for minimum viable product in my answer and i agree with your comment. there's a bigger scope of a refactor here. while i'm at it, i'd suggest the ctor not doing any work besides accepting its dependencies. i'd move the try/catch logic into another method (which would inevitably be IAWSDynamoDbManager.TryGetAWSCredentials)